# How could I fix the unquoted nan value in JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, websocket, socket.io, nan

An external C routine called in a Python script returns a "big" and "deep" JSON that contains here and there a few unquoted `nan` values for certain keys.

Because of these values, the JSON appears as invalid and it can't be sent over a websocket for instance.

e.g.

```
{'myKey': nan}
```

**How could fix this JSON without having to check exhaustively each value?**  Fixing the source generating the JSON is not an option. I need to fix the JSON before I send it over the websocket.

Is there a way that I could substitute the unquoted `nan` by something that wouldn't cause an error when I try to `emit` via WebSocket.

Alternatively, Is there a way to configure [`python-socket.io`](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to allow these unquoted `nan` values? My current research, says it can't.

### AN IDEA (?)

I am thinking, I could stringify, replace the `nan` string by something that works, and JSONify again.

But what could I replace the unquoted `nan` with?

### UPDATE

`json.dumps` to convert to string

`replace("nan", "'nan'")` or better, use @Jaco answer

`json.loads` to create the JSON obj

Comment: Convert json to string, and replace any nan with string "nan"?

Comment: yeah that's what  I suggested as an edit to my post. Will try that. Just now I am looking at the `replacer` param in the `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert your JSON to a string, you can then use a regular expression to replace all instances of `nan` with `null` and then use `JSON.load` to convert it back to JSON.

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\bnan\b',flags=re.IGNORECASE)
re.sub(regex, ' null ', "{'myKey': nan}")
```

Comment: Yes:-), added it to my answer

Answer (score 1):

`simplejson` package can be used to handle NaN values in json. It's dumps method takes ignore_nan as an agrument to handle nan values. Default value of ignore_nan is False and should be set as True to handle nan values.

```
import simplejson

response = requests.get(url)  # assume response from url contains some NaN values e.g. {"key": NaN}
normalized_str = simplejson.dumps(response.json(), ignore_nan=True) # this gives string with NaN represented as null e.g. '{"key": null}'
new_dict = simplejson.loads(normalized_str) # this gives back dict from string with null represented as None e.g. {"key": None}
```